# How to play a particular item from media play list?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using windows media player in windows forms application. I have 10 media items in my playlist. foo, foo1,foo2,foo3 ....

Now my playlist is playing lets say foo1. Now on button click I want to play item foo6. How do I play this ? i.e. how do I change my current playing item too foo6 ?

If this is not clear please comment, I will add more information.

Edit: Following is the code for creating a new playlist.

```
WindowsMediaPlayerClass wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayerClass();
playlist = WMPLeft.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("myplaylist1");
for (int i = 0; i < FOO.Length; i++)
{
    media = WMPLeft.newMedia(FOO[i]);                          
    playlist.appendItem(media);  
}
```

What I want is something like this

```
WMPLeft.playlist.Item(3).play();
```

This is wrong. But this is the kind of code I want.

Comment: not clear. do you want shuffle in the media player list?

Comment: Yes shuffle. But not a random item. Play a particular item.

Comment: so when `foo1` is playing, you want `foo6` to play on button click??. what if `foo2` is playing????

Comment: yes on click of button I want to simply change the current playing item. No matter which file is playing.

Comment: how do you pick items from the playlist. is the playlist a file?. show the code you use to play the first file

Comment: @PreciousTijesunimi please check the edits I have added.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36995/discussion-between-akash-deshpande-and-precioustijesunimi)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much research I have found this msdn link which shows how to do what I wanted.

```
// Declare a variable to hold the position of the media item 
// in the current playlist. An arbitrary value is supplied here.
int index = 3;

// Get the media item at the fourth position in the current playlist.
WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = player.currentPlaylist.get_Item(index);

// Play the media item.
player.Ctlcontrols.playItem(media);
```

[LINK to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Post some of the information in the link and why you found it helpful, then you can help everyone and they'll upvote your answer.